# Подготовка данных для кластеризации схем, содержащих элементы на прямоугольной системе координат

Tags: c#, алгоритм, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, кластеризация

Есть текстовые файлы формата `scheme{N}.txt`, которые содержат строки в формате:

```
x – значение координаты X, 
y – значение координаты Y, 
w – ширина элемента,
y – высота элемента,
type – тип элемента (1-прямоугольник, 2-круг)
```

Описывающие элементы находящиеся на схеме. *Один файл – одна схема, одна строка – один элемент*.

К примеру, есть вот такие две схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со своими текстовыми файлами:

**scheme1.txt**

```
200,200,400,100,1
1100,200,400,100,1
700,450,350,200,2
```

**scheme2.txt**

```
200,200,400,200,1
1100,200,400,200,1
700,300,350,150,2
350,550,950,100,1
```

---

### Задача

Таких файлов понятное дело сотни, и теперь необходимо с помощью кластеризации сгруппировать эти схемы, где в одной группе будут находится схемы (наименования файлов `scheme{N}.txt`) с наиболее *похожей компоновкой элементов и их пространственным расположением*. К примеру, приведённые выше две схемы вполне можно считать похожими и тем самым определить в одной группе.

---

### Вопрос

Согласно поставленной задаче, как подготовить данные для кластеризации? Понятное дело, что это ML и чёткой рекомендации быть не может, но я не знаю с чего начать. Если пробовать даже с помощью признакового описания, так как получается, что объект-схему (обучающий образец), нужно описать *совокупностью объектов-элементов*. Подскажите направление, в котором мне искать решение.

---

### ML-фреймворки для .NET

Будучи .NET разработчик, я все же планирую реализовать все это дело при помощи одного из ML-фреймворка для .NET: [ML.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning), который сейчас в самом разгаре своей разработки, но делать кластеризацию уже позволяет или [Accord.NET Framework](https://github.com/accord-net/framework), товарищ наиболее богатый своим API, в силу своего возраста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример на Python (с использованием модулей: Numpy, Pandas, SciKit-Learn).

Исходные файлы:

1.csv:

```
x,y,width,height,type
200,200,400,100,1
1100,200,400,100,1
700,450,350,200,2
```

2.csv:

```
x,y,width,height,type
200,200,400,200,1
1100,200,400,200,1
700,300,350,150,2
350,550,950,100,1
```

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

d1 = pd.read_csv("c:/temp/1.csv")
d2 = pd.read_csv("c:/temp/2.csv")
```

расчёт `cosine similarity`:

```
In [100]: cosine_similarity(d1, d2)
Out[100]:
array([[0.98270769, 0.73080017, 0.83385344, 0.98572935],
       [0.69779772, 0.99657013, 0.97078395, 0.6421735 ],
       [0.83795773, 0.93404102, 0.98752559, 0.79018104]])
```

т.е. считается схожесть первой строки первого файла со всеми 4-мя строками второго файла (получили 4 элемента в первой строке для первой строки первого файла, и т.д.) Т.е. в результате мы получаем матрицу размерности `(число строк первого файла, число строк второго файла)`.

Можно взять среднее всей матрицы как меру схожести файлов (надо попробовать этот подход на практике со многими файлами, чтобы понять насколько он "рабочий"):

```
In [101]: cosine_similarity(d1, d2).mean()
Out[101]: 0.8658434435935128
```

Comment: Изучая вопрос дальше, вижу, что на основе таких значений (0.86...) я получу _матрицу сходства_. Далее, использую один из методов кластеризации, к примеру _иерархический_, и получу кластеры. А как получить _predict model_, куда на вход будет подаваться матрица, а ответом будет кластер куда она больше подходит?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в задачах кластеризации мы выделяем / группируем объекты в кластеры по расстоянию или схожести между объектами.

В вашем случае объектами являются файлы (схемы).

Вам придётся реализовать функцию для подсчета расстояния (коэффициент схожести) для двух файлов и попробовать использовать её. В качестве примера можно взять ["cosine similarity"](http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/). Перед расчетом схожести лучше всего преобразовать последний столбец матрицы (тип элемента) таким образом, чтобы он был приблизительно одной размерности с остальными столбцами - например заменить тип фигуры (цифры `1`, `2`) на квадратный корень площади данной фигуры. Тогда все 5 столбцов будут измеряться в одинаковых величинах и при подсчете `"cosine similarity"` значения столбцов будут рассматриваться как соответствующие координаты вектора в пяти-мерном пространстве.

PS как это сделать в `Accord.NET` я не знаю...

Comment: К примеру, насколько правильно будет просуммировать все столбцы (признаки), чтобы в каждом файле оставалась только одна строка (вектор) `x, y, w...`? У меня сложность в том, чтобы сделать файл *одним объектом*. Сейчас он содержит несколько объектов.

Comment: если просуммировать то получите "среднюю температуру по больнице, включая морг" ;) А в чем проблема читать по файлам и находить между матрицами `cosine similarity`?

Comment: то есть, _один файл_ это у нас _одна матрица_, верно?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, да

Comment: Делать сранение _двух векторов_ я смог, но вот не могу понять как вычислить степень схожести _двух матриц_. Или вы имеете ввиду сначала привести обе матрицы в векторы и затем делать сравнение уже векторов?